# Redis Lexicographical Range Search Inconsistent Results

Tags: search, redis, sortedset

I am trying to do a lexicographical range search on a Redis [sorted set](https://redis.io/commands#sorted_set), but getting inconsistent results based on my understanding of how this feature works. The results are similar when using `ZRANGECOUNT`, `ZRANGEBYLEX`, and `ZREMRANGEBYLEX`.

> **Working Queries**

This is an example of my set with 3 elements just using `ZRANGE`.

```
redis> ZRANGE myset 0 -1 
0  00000000022xm26hax001
1  00000000022xm26hax002
2  00000000022xm26hax003
```

I can also get all of the elements lexicographically.

```
redis> ZRANGEBYLEX myset - +
0  00000000022xm26hax001
1  00000000022xm26hax002
2  00000000022xm26hax003
```

Doing a range search by leaving off the last 3 characters also works as expected.

```
redis> ZRANGEBYLEX myset [00000000022xm26hax [00000000022xm26hax\xff
0  00000000022xm26hax001
1  00000000022xm26hax002
2  00000000022xm26hax003
```

Adjusting the range arguments I can select just the first two elements as well.

```
redis> ZRANGEBYLEX myset [00000000022xm26hax001 [00000000022xm26hax002\xff
0  00000000022xm26hax001
1  00000000022xm26hax002
```

A short start seems to be acceptable:

```
redis> ZRANGEBYLEX myset [00000000022x [00000000022xm26hax001\xff
0  00000000022xm26hax001
```

> **Problem Queries**

I run into problems however when I try to select using a shorter version of the string - these all return **0** results when I would expect them to return **3**.

```
ZRANGEBYLEX myset [00000000022xm26h [00000000022xm26h\xff
ZRANGEBYLEX myset [00000000022x [00000000022x\xff
```

But then adding back just the "m" makes it return all three elements again.

```
redis> ZRANGEBYLEX myset [00000000022xm [00000000022xm\xff
0  00000000022xm26hax001
1  00000000022xm26hax002
2  00000000022xm26hax003
```

Can someone explain this behavior? What is the correct way to get back all elements that start with `"00000000022x"` given my example dataset?

Why does `ZRANGEBYLEX myset [00000000022x [00000000022x\xff` return no results but `ZRANGEBYLEX myset [00000000022xm [00000000022xm\xff` returns all the results - just adding the "m" seems to make it work as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this could ultimately not be determined by the question I posted. For clarity I left out the score of each sorted set entry which was meant to be an expiration timestamp. Unfortunately the documentation for [`ZRANGEBYLEX`](https://redis.io/commands/zrangebylex) says:

> When all the elements in a sorted set are inserted with the same score, in order to force lexicographical ordering, this command returns all the elements in the sorted set at key with a value between min and max.

My entries did not have the same score so they were not being sorted lexicographically.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like Redis to resolve escape codes in your strings (like the `\xff` in your examples), you need to wrap the strings in quotation marks.

In other words, this will treat `\xff` as byte 255:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> ZRANGEBYLEX myset [00000000022xm26hax001 "[00000000022xm26ha\xff"
1) "00000000022xm26hax001"
2) "00000000022xm26hax002"
3) "00000000022xm26hax003"
```

Whereas this treats `\xff` as four bytes (92, 120, 102, 102):

```
127.0.0.1:6379> ZRANGEBYLEX myset [00000000022xm26hax001 [00000000022xm26ha\xff
(empty list or set)
```

This explains your confusing results.